# Showing XElement in Wpf

Tags: wpf, xml, text, wpf-controls, xelement

I have Question. This has a property Body which is an XElement. How Can I show This as Text in a Wpf application?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could bind to `Body.Value` property. (That is, the `Value` property of `XElement`.)